# Custom styles inside a component in angular full calendar

Tags: html, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have used FullCalendar inside my angular application. I have created a reusable component using the FullCalendar and use it like this,

```html
<app-full-calendar 
  [building]="selectedBuilding"
  [newEvent]="newEvent"
  (clickedEvent)="clickedEvent($event)"
  (clickedDate)="dateClicked($event)"
  [updatedEvent]="updatedEvent"
  [deleteEvent]="deletedId"
 ></app-full-calendar>
```

when ever necessary.

The issue is there are custom styling necessities such as changing the cursor of events. In order to achieve this, I have to add custom styles inside the component. But so far I was not able to find any solution.